# How to write a composition function in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

if theta and lambda are two trees/sets, how would I write this function to see if they are the same and if they are the same then the true function will keep them but the false part should remove them and apply lambda to theta.

```
let compose theta lambda = 
  match (theta = lambda) with
    | true -> (match theta with 
          | [] -> "{" ^ (format theta) ^ "}" (* "/" ^ (Printf.sprintf "v%d" theta.var) ^ "}" *)
          | lambda :: _ -> "{" ^ (format theta) ^ "/" ^ "}" (* (Printf.sprintf "v%d" theta.var) ^ ", " ^ (format lambda.tree) ^ "/" ^  (Printf.sprintf "v%d" lambda.var) ^ "}"*)
      )
    | false -> ??
    ;;
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Try to write in a clearer way and maybe add some small example of input and output of the function.

Comment: Style note: `match exp with true -> ... | false -> ...` is really just `if exp then ... else ...`.  Alternately you can avoid the nesting with `match (theta = lambda), theta with true, [] -> ... | true, (lambda::_) -> ... | false, _ -> ...`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to provide a lot more background if you want help with this problem. You don't give enough details for someone (at least me) to give a helpful answer.

Just one observation: you can't normally use the polymorphic equality operator `=` to compare two trees that represent sets. Depending on the design of your trees, there are usually many representations for the same set. The polymorphic equality operator will treat all the different representations as being different. In other words, you need to write a domain-specific equality comparison yourself. If you use the OCaml Set module, you can use `S.equal`.